# Use conditional when statement in Ansible, to only run a task in playbook when a certain version of a package is called

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Hi I am new to Ansible and what I want to do something like this:

for example -

the task in my playbook:

```
    - name: install one specific version of Apache
      yum:
        name: httpd-{{ version }}
        state: present
        when: {{ version }} ==  2.2.29-1.4.amzn1
```

The variables in my Vars file :

```
version: 
    - 2.2.29-1.4.amzn1
    - 2.2.30-1.5.amzn1
    - 2.3.31-1.6.amzn1 
   so on .....
```

So I want the task to only run when I pass in a specific version of Apache, no matter where it is in that list of versions. In this case its  2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.

Comment: The use case is not clear. What is *version*? Is it a list of allowed versions, or is it a single version used in the task? Where does the version used in the task come from? See the answer. Do **not** comment there if this is not what you want. Instead, [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    versions: 
    - 2.2.29-1.4.amzn1
    - 2.2.30-1.5.amzn1
    - 2.3.31-1.6.amzn1
  tasks:
    - name: Sanity
      debug:
        msg: "[WARNING] httpd-{{ version }} can't be installed."
      when: version not in versions
    - name: Install one specific version of Apache
      debug:
        msg: "Install httpd-{{ version }}"
      when: version in versions
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e version=2.2.29-1.4.amzn1

PLAY [test_11] ****************************************************************

TASK [Sanity] *****************************************************************
skipping: [test_11]

TASK [Install one specific version of Apache] *********************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: Install httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e version=2.2.28-1.4.amzn1

PLAY [test_11] *****************************************************************

TASK [Sanity] ******************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: '[WARNING] httpd-2.2.28-1.4.amzn1 can''t be installed.'

TASK [Install one specific version of Apache] **********************************
skipping: [test_11]
```